# Migration Swift 3.0 - Podfile with RNCryptor and other libraries

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, rncryptor

I just upgraded Swift to 3.0 and I have many problems with librairies.
When I compile, there are 72 issues only for the library RNCryptor.
Why ?

Comment: Version 5.0 is Swift 3. The current problem is in getting the podspec published, which is something I have to re-research every time it comes up. I typically don't deal with CocoaPods. See https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor/issues/214. I'm happy to accept a list of "do this and CP is happy" or a PR. I have no projects that require it.

Answer (score 1):

The stable branch of RNCryptor was written in Swift 2 (plus other languages), which is not compatible with Swift 3. You'll have to wait until they have completed their upgrade, which seems to be in progress.

Check all your other third-party libraries as well.

Comment: Is it impossible to use libraries written in swift 3.0 and libraries written in swift 2.3 ?

Comment: Unfortunatley yes, both at the source code level and at the binary level. It is planned to fix this with Swift 4. But it will only work between Swift 4 and even later versions.

Comment: Have anyone contacted RNCyptor authors to know about swift 3 support date?

Comment: It should be ready. Release 5.0 introduced Swift 3 support. The latest release is 5.0.1.

Comment: I tried with 5.0. I replaced RNCryptor.h and RNCryptor.swift with latest. Then opened in xcode 8.1. Converted to swift 3.0. But still it shows compilation error  unknown type name "RNEncryptor" and "RNDecryptor".

Comment: Your error message isn't related to the original question. Start a new question and clearliy specify how you installed RNCryptor (probably the manual way) and whether you use it from Swift or Objective-C.